# ¿Why oauth_callback parameter don´t redirect? (intuit quickbooks api - oauth1.0a)

Tags: php, api, oauth, callback, sha1

I´m having a problem with my oauth request, right now i´m receiving

```
oauth_token_secret=<Token>&oauth_token=<Token>&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

But it never redirects with the variables to execute the next step.

> I´m passing the oauth_callback with urlencode() php, of course i have already tried to pass it without the percent encoding, and still doesn´t work...

This callback url is double percent encode with urlencode() php on the HMAC-SHA1 coding. By the way, is the only way to obtain the tokens back, otherwise it returns signature-invalid.

> I´ve already left a question in the support developers section of the
>   api, but no answer.

¿What can be happening here?

This Api is from intuit quickbooks

**Url sample:**

```
https%3A%2F%2FMyWeb.com%2FMyController
```

This is the code sample for the HMAC-SHA1

```
// HMAC-SHA1 encoding to get the tokens from quickbooks Api

$callback = urlencode('https://MyWeb.com/MyController'); // First urlencode of the callback url set on the grantUrl setup()


$action = 'GET'; // The Action to perform the request
$action .= '&'; // Append an &
$action .= urlencode('https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token'); // Append the baseUrl request url encoded
$action .= '&'; // Append an &
$action .= urlencode('oauth_callback=' . $callback . '&oauth_consumer_key=<consumerKey>&oauth_nonce=<nonce>&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=<timestamp>&oauth_version=1.0'); // Append Parameters url encoded (callbak must be encoded twice)

$secretKey = urlencode('keyHere'); // Set the secretKey urlEncoded
$secretKey .= '&'; // Append an &

$resultant = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $action, $secretKey, TRUE)); // Get the hash_hmac with a base64_encode.

$f_result = urlencode($resultant); // url encode the $resultant to put it as the signature
```

This is the query url

```
https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token?oauth_callback=https%3A%2F%2FMyWeb.com%2FMyController&oauth_consumer_key=<ConsumerKey>&oauth_nonce=<nonce>&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=<timestamp>&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=E0SagYvSY6wxpjp2QRIIP%2Bmz%2Fiw%3D
```

> This is exectuted trough a javascript generated button, according to the API docs.

this is the sample:

```
<script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere-1.3.3.js">
</script>
<!-- Implement the setup function for the connect button -->
<script>
intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
    grantUrl: 'queryUrl post above',
            datasources: {
            quickbooks : true,
            payments : true
            },
            paymentOptions:{
                intuitReferred : true
            }
});
</script>
```

Comment: please include an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi!! Extra info added.